# Selenium can't find elements even after timeouts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to scrap a web page, but I am having problem when I try to access the element after the click action.

When the loop starts the second time I get "`stale element reference`: `element is not attached to the page document`".

I understand that Selenium can't found element - checkbox for another `fare` and `departuretime` div. I tried to put all kind of timeouts, try blocks, refresh the page. But in the end the result is the same - can't find element or get `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`.

Maybe somebody has ideas on what is the problem? I just run out of ideas, how to fix it:(

P.S I am using Python, Selenium and webdriver.chrome.

**UPDATE:**

I changed webDriver to Firefox geckodriver, deleted  "wait.until(EC.title_contains(fare.get_attribute('id')))" at the end of the loop and add  "driver.implicitly_wait(10)" in the end. Now it is kind of working. Tried to add implicity_wait to code with chrome driver but it was causing the same exceptions. So can the problem be with the chrome webdriver???

My code example:

```
fares =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='inputselect 
standardlowfare']/div[1]/input[starts- 
with(@id,'FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare') and @type='radio']")


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    # elem = wait.until(EC.title_contains((fare.get_attribute('id'))))
    # wait.until(EC.refreshed(EC.staleness_of(fare.get_attribute('id'))))
    # driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    # wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
for fare in fares:

  fare.click()
  print("clicked " ) 
  time.sleep(5)  
    # driver.get(driver.current_url)
    # wait.until(EC.title_contains(('selectiontable')))

  departureTime = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//* [@id='ctl00_MainContent_ipcAvaDay_upnlResSelection']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td")
  print ("Departure time " + departureTime.text) 
  wait.until(EC.title_contains(fare.get_attribute('id')))
```

Comment: i am confused, you are getting the element id and compare it to the page title? Can you give more information what is the goal?

Comment: Put your `fares =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@....")` inside the for loop.

Comment: Infern0 yeah..; After hours to find the problem I probably can make stupid mistake...My main goal is : check the radio -> collect data from new uploaded element( table from where I am trying to get departure time. It is NOT iframe). Then check another radio and do the same thing. I hope it is make sense

Comment: I am not sure, but can the problem be with chrome webDriver? I changed the webdriver into geckodriver,add driver.implicitly_wait(10) int the end of the loop and deleted wait.until. And now it is kind of working

Comment: Try running chrome in headless mode with implicit wait only.

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException.` on which line? `departureTime` or `fares`?

Comment: when click() triggers new navigation, all of the original references to elements will become stale